# Creating Bean only for embedded tomcat or embedded server

Tags: spring-boot

I want @Bean to be created if application is running in embedded container. That bean should not be created if application is run on external tomcat. Is there any way we can create @Conditional annotation to create bean only if application is running in embedded tomcat.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a custom condition, you could use a Spring profile that's only enabled when you're using an embedded container. When you deploy a Spring Boot application to Tomcat its main method isn't run, making it a good place to enable the profile that you only want to be active in the embedded case.

Something like this:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So34924050Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    @Profile("embedded")
    public EmbeddedOnlyBean embeddedOnlyBean() {
        return new EmbeddedOnlyBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(So34924050Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(So34924050Application.class).profiles("embedded").run(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the [`@ConditionalOnClass`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnClass.html) annotation, to only create the TomcatFactory if the **embedded** Tomcat classes exist. If this doesn't suit your purposes, there are a multitude of `@CondtionalOn...` classes that you could utilise to conditionally create a bean. e.g. `@CondtionalOnProperty`.

i.e.

```java
// If running tomcat embedded, ensure that JNDI is enabled.
@Bean
@ConditionalOnClass(name = {
        "org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory",
        "org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer",
        "org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat"
})
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(final Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This code is not working, it's still called on embedded tomcat and standalone tomcat too....

Answer (score 1):

You can customize configuration for embedded tomcat by using the same condition as in Spring Boot's AutoConfiguration class [`EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/embedded/EmbeddedWebServerFactoryCustomizerAutoConfiguration.java#L53) (version 2.1.0.  here).

```java
@ConditionalOnClass({ Tomcat.class, UpgradeProtocol.class })
public class TomcatEmbeddedConfig {

    @Bean
    ConfigurableServletWebServerFactory webServerFactory() {
        return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() { 
            // Configure embedded tomcat here
        }
    }

}
```